# How to enable certain cover images to be replaced by an admin user in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I want to enable my client to easily replace individual images directly from their website's front-end.  Say for example there are 5 product images on their homepage and the client will want to change one (or all) of them from time to time.

Do I need to create 5 separate uploaders with CarrierWave (one for each of the 5 product images), and then add a column for each to a shared 'products' model?

As a complete Rails and Ruby noob I think this will work, but it seems a bit convoluted and not very DRY.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Alxs

Comment: why not just add an attribute to the images called `featured` or something and then just pull the `featured` images to display?

Comment: You should add some more info about your schema, including how the images relate to products (does a product have one image?  5 images?  As many as the user wants?) etc

Comment: @engineersmnky - the client needs to be able to update images via mobile device.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - All products are closely related ie. the product model could be named 'ice-cream' and the individual product images could be, 'butter pecan', 'rum n raisin', 'chocolate chip', 'tutti frutti', 'vanilla' etc.  There will only ever be one picture of each and they're similar enough items to all just be labelled 'ice-cream'.  But the client will want to choose which image goes in which place-holder.

Comment: I am not sure what the platform of the image update has to do with this but like I said why can't you just have a `featured` Boolean as part of the images model and when this is checked then this is the display image. When they upload a new image it could be marked as `featured` and the previous one would be set to false?

Comment: @engineersmnky - I see what you're saying now. You're right, I could add a featured boolean in the image model to flag images as 'featured', but how would I make it remove the flag from the previous ones as they're replaced?

Comment: add callback hooks to the model to handle the changes in `:create` and `:update` e.g. `before_create` or `after_update`

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, that's a big help.